# How to implement an easy workflow with a task, if task approved create an item in another task, otherwise do nothing

Tags: workflow, tasks

I am building a SharePoint 2010 portal. I have for example LISTA and LISTB. On LISTA I have created a workflow. In this workflow I have created an advanced task action. Now I would like to configure it that when the approver approves the task, there needs to created a new item in LISTB. Otherwise do nothing in the workflow.

How can I read the outcome value of the task?

Comment: By "outcome value", you mean "if the task is approved" ? If so, there are many tutorials that show you up how to do this in google (let me 5 minutes, to find one). If not, I don't understand what is your real problem.

Comment: yes thats correct. Thats  my problem. I know how it works in SharePoint 2013 with the SharePoint 2013 workflow platform.

Comment: You can have a look at this [post](http://www.openhost-network.com/workflow-sharepoint/) and translate it if you need (it uses French), look at the last part, when the task is being approved, its send an email. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451095/how-do-i-create-an-approval-workflow-that-updates-the-list-item-that-started-the) too. And finally the official [office blog](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx)

Comment: (Could not edit my comment after 5 min =/) I'm sure [this plain text how to](http://www.threewill.com/2014/03/configure-approval-workflows-with-sharepoint-designer/) will help you

Comment: Thanks. I was needed to create an if operation where I check if the current task:Result is equal to "Approved". Inside this if operation I have an action where I create a new listitem in LISTB.

Comment: the "I was needed" means that it solves your problem ? or at least answers your question ? If so, answer your own post with interesting things you've found and links you used. May help ppl in the future.

Comment: It is just a summary of the steps I did. But I have found it by your answers. All credits to you Nico.

Comment: No problem, I was just telling you that an post mark as an answer when you'll have finish your job would be great :)